# Setting heightForRowAt indexPath for multiple rows to 0

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, tableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have an array of integers and I am trying to set the UITableViewCell height to 50 for all rows within the array, and the remaining rows to 0.
Using Swift 3, my array returns `[0,1,3,6]` and I am looping through all elements within the array using a for loop.

In my `heightForRowAt indexPath` function, I am comparing the `indexPath.row` to these values and setting the height appropriately. However, it will only work for the first element, and not all.

Simply put in code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if isSearching == true{
        searchBarIndexs.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
        for allvalues in searchBarIndexs{
            if indexPath.row == allvalues{
                return 52
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    } else {
        return 52
    }
    return 52
}

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if isSearching{
            return searchBarIndexs.count
        } else {
            return usernames.count
        }

    }




override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! usersProfileTableViewCell
            cell.userUsernameLabel.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
            cell.userIdLabel.text = userIDs[indexPath.row]

            self.allimages[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data,error) in
                if let imageData = data {
                    if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData){
                        cell.profileImage.image = downloadedImage

                    }
                }
            }

        return cell
    }
```

What logic am I missing so that the height is set appropriately for all elements within array and not just the first? I have tried other approaches using indexPath.contains, but to no avail.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your complete `heightForRowAt` method (as text).

Comment: Hi rmaddy, sorry about that, i've indented properly and included my complete heightForRowAt method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't loop. Just check the current `indexPath`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if isSearching {
        return searchBarIndexs.contains(indexPath.row) ? 52 : 0
    } else {
        return 52
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @rmmaddy Thank you for your assistance and prompt reply. I am still trying to incorporate this fix as I haven't had much practice with inline statements. Basically, I am filtering the data in a tableview using a search bar, but using this approach it is only returning specific searches, so trying to see what is missing.

Comment: This is the code you claim you want. The logic here is if you are searching, return a height of 52 only for rows found in the `searchBarIndexs` array. If that's not working then either your requirement isn't correct or your population of `searchBarIndexs` isn't correct.

Comment: To show that my searchBarIndexs array is correct based on my search bar: On my users table when I input "M" into the search bar and print the searchBarIndexs array, I am returned with [0, 1, 3, 6] with the tableview displaying 3 results however. Within the search bar, when I input "S" my searchBarIndexs array is returning [2, 5] with nothing being displayed in tableview

Comment: `return searchBarIndexs.count` needs to be `return usernames.count` in your `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: Silly me.. Thank you so much for your continued assistance and prompt replies. Appreciate your help immensely, can't thank you enough!